# Why i get a NoneType error if i read a html file?

Tags: python, html, text, beautifulsoup

I tried to read a html file, and scraping the relevant information. 
This code works, if I open it in text format, but if I open it at html format, I get the next error message:

```
"File "C:\Python27\TEST5.py", line 29, in <module>
    for record in tab6col.find_all('tr'):
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_all'"
```

What is the difference between this two methods? Why isn't work when I'm trying open it in html format?

```js
filename=r'output.csv'

resultcsv=open(filename,"wb")
output=csv.writer(resultcsv, delimiter=';',quotechar = '"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC, encoding='latin-1')
 
f = codecs.open('proba.html', 'r')
x = f.read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(x, 'lxml')
 
tab6col = soup.find('table', { "class" : "tab6col" })
datatable=[]
for record in tab6col.find_all('tr'):
    temp_data = []
    for data in record.find_all('td'):
        temp_data.append(data.text.encode('latin-1'))
    datatable.append(temp_data)
  

output.writerows(datatable)

resultcsv.close()
```

Comment: _"if i open it in .text format"_ What does that mean? Are you saying the file has a `.text` extension (like `proba.text`)? That can't possibly make any difference.

Comment: I saved a html source in proba.text format and in proba.html format too.
If i try to run the code with proba.text, it it working, if i try with proba.html, i get this error

Comment: Then something must be different in `proba.text`. If you rename `proba.text` to `proba.html` it'll work.

Comment: I know. I just want to understand, why i get this error message.

Comment: If i open the source a webpage, and i select all (CTRL+A) and save it in a word, save and run it it is work.

If i do it with CTRL+S and save directly .html format it isnt work.